# Enabling Sprockets Debug Mode in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, asset-pipeline, sprockets

How can I enable the debug mode of Sprockets in Sinatra.
I prefer the assets to be not concatenated while developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a debug option for Sprockets itself. I could be wrong, but I didn't see anything about debug mode in their source.

I did happen to see things relating to the Rails development mode in the [sprockets-rails source](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/lib/sprockets/rails/helpers/rails_helper.rb)

Edit:
I might suggest something for Sinatra like [Sinatra-assetpack](http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/#assets_serve) which as development and production modes built in.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am using sinatra-asset pack. Do you know how to enable/disable debug mode in asset-pack without forcing sinatra itself into development/producton?

Comment: On the package, there is a `to_development_html` which will output the html for development mode. You could doubly check to see if `settings.environment` is `production` while also checking if `settings.asset_debug` is `true`, then you could choose whichever tag you need: `= css :application` or `css = assets.packages['application.css']; css.to_development_html`.  Not the cleanest solution, but it's a way to get development mode assets in production environments.